# MySQL Help Optimize This - Count Everything Within 24 Hours of Min Record

Tags: mysql

[image]

I'm probably approaching this all wrong, but how can I best do this query? I only want the number of records within 1 day of the the min timestamp for each studyID. This query gets the answer I need but it takes forever with a million records. The subquery runs by itself in seconds and the main query without the subquery runs in seconds, but this runs terribly slow......

```
SELECT st.StudyID,COUNT(*)
FROM Studies st
JOIN(SELECT StudyID,DATE_ADD(MIN(TimeStamp),INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE) AS MaxTime 
FROM Studies GROUP BY StudyID) AS d1
ON d1.StudyID = st.Study.ID
WHERE st.TimeStamp<=d1.MaxTime
GROUP BY st.StudyID
```

The output should be this obviously....

```
ID COUNT(*) 
2  3    
4  4
```

Comment: Queries about optimization should include a `EXPLAIN <query>` output and a `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` output for every table involved in the SQL

Comment: Please post the execution plan.

Comment: Yep, as well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, we really need to see that EXPLAIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a query plan, I would guess your query is reading the whole table twice. There's no much you can do about it (since this strategy looks already optimal), if the table does have a massive number of rows.

A covering index may help, and I would try the following one:

```
create index ix1 on Studies (StudyID, TimeStamp);
```